# Defining constructors in a class that uses pointers (C++)

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Okay, so this is my first question on this site, and I'm fairly new to C++. I am trying to create a class of functions that puts the members of various campus clubs into their respective clubs. I was given this class skeleton to follow, *but I'm not sure how to define the three constructors*, especially how to use the variables that are inside of the parameters. You can pretty much ignore all of the public functions except the constructors. Any ideas?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    class Club
   {
    public:
     Club();
     Club(Club &c);
     Club(string cname);
     void addMember(string name);
     void removeMember(string name);
     const string getClubName();
     void loadClub();
     const bool isMember(string name);
     const string getAllMembers();
     friend Club mergeClubs(Club& c1, Club& c2);
     ~Club();
    private:
     string *members;
     int numMembers;
     string clubName;
    };
```

Comment: If we can ignore everything except the operators and constructor, I would advise you to post without the extra clutter.

Comment: You are going to have to figure out what you want your initial values of `numMembers`, `clubName` and `*members` for an empty club.

Comment: You probably also want `vector<string> members`, not `string * members`

Comment: The semantics of `string *members;` are totally unclear. This question cannot be answered without that information. In general, it is simply not recommended to store objects using a pointer to object. A pointer to object is not a container of objects. This is error prone, and I would ban it in a coding standard.

Comment: I would say that `set<string>` might be a better fit than vector, considering that the `removeMember(string)` semantics will be troublesome for non-unique strings in a vector. I assume that the OP wants each string to be unique in the collection.

Comment: did you try to make at least one definition? The cool thing about C++ is that if you define two functions with the same name but different parameters, the compiler will attempt to link to the "right" one (with matching parameter signature). So - write something, look at the warnings / errors, then come back.

Comment: Slight rant, but I keep seeing people use pointers when STL containers are a better choice.  Is this what our instructors are teaching these days?

Comment: Thanks for the input but I actually can't change the code given...my professor gave this code to us to start out with, and we have to use it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three constructors:  the default `Club()`, the copy constructor `Club(Club &c)` and a third one `Club(string cname)`.

For the default, you're going to have to decide what all the default values for your private members are.

For the copy constructor, all you need to do is copy everything from `&c` into your own record.  So for instance you can do:

```
numMembers = c.numMembers ;
```

For the third one, you have to decide what `cname` is and what you should do with it.

For the copy constructor, you do have one tricky decision to make.  What does it mean to copy `string * members;`  You might think you could just say `members= c.members ;` but then if the original `Club` gets resized, the copy will be pointing to invalid memory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array of strings, just use a vector, then you don't need the "numMembers" either.

```
class Club
{
public:
  ...

    void addMember(string name) { members.push_back(name); }
    void removeMemeber(string name) { members.erase(std::remove(members.begin(), members.end(), name), members.end()); }

  ...

private:
    vector<string> members;
    string clubName;
};
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach, because the function `removeMember` (without the typo) advertises through its name that its role is to remove **one** member, while your implementation removes **all** members matching `name`.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I actually can't change the code given...my professor gave this code to us to start out with, and we have to use it as it is.

Comment: True SirDarius, of course we'd have to know what the requirements are and it probably would be better to write a remove single and a remove all function.